# Выполнение действий после Pull в PhpStorm

Tags: git, phpstorm, ide, контроль-версий, git-pull

Необходимо запустить действие (скрипт/программу) после выполнения обновления файлов с сервера (pull). Требуется внести изменения в PHP файл в котором массив с настройками, т.к. у разных участников команды свои локальные настройки.

IDE: PhpStorm, VCS: GitHub

Answer (score 2):

Я бы посмотрел в сторону [git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-Git). Это возможность git выполнять какие-то скрипты по определенным событиям как на стороне клиента, так и на стороне сервера.

Вот здесь [здесь](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) есть перечень всех возможных hook-ов. В чистом виде hook-а на pull нет, но есть post-merge. После каждого pull выполняется merge и этот hook отработает. Надо только учитывать, что у вас могуть быть merge-и помимо pull и в этом случае скрипт тоже будет отрабатывать.

Comment: благодарю. но используется GitHub. причем только из GUI PhpStorm

Comment: Это не имеет никакого значения. Под всем, что вы перечислили "лежит" обычный git репозиторий. Когда вы в PhpStorm говорите выполнить команду Pull, он вызывает команду `git pull` и забирает изменения из удаленного репозитория на GitHub в ваш локальный репозиторий. Все что я предлагаю, добавить hook в этот локальный репозиторий (папочка `.git` в корне проекта) hook, который будет запускаться после слияние изменений, полученных из удаленного репозитория с локальным (`merge`).

Comment: благодарю, разобрался. отличное работает. причем даже под windows стандартный bash.